# "Array to string conversion" al Subir imágenes en Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tengo esta función en larevel 10 con la que quiero subir imágenes para después usarlas en un slider dinámico pero a la hora de salvar me me da un error:

> Array to string conversion

el error ocurre al ejecutar
if($slider->save()):
ya he revisado todas las variables y contienen los valores que deberían tener y no se cual es la causa pudiran decirme cual es mi error muchas gracias.

```php
public function postSliderAdd(Request $request)
{

    $rules = [
        'file_image' => 'required'
    ];

    $messages = [
        'file_image.required' => 'Seleccione una imagen'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
    if($validator->fails()):
        return redirect('/admin/slider')->withErrors($validator)->with('message', 'Se ha producido un error')->with('typealert', 'danger')->withInput();
    else:
        if($request->hasFile('file_image')):

            $path = '/'.date('Y-m-d');
            $fileExt = trim($request->file('file_image')->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $upload_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.slider.root'); 
            $name = Str::slug(str_replace($fileExt, '', $request->file('file_image')->getClientOriginalName()));

            $filename = rand(1, 9999).'-'.$name.'.'.$fileExt;
            $file_file = $upload_path.'/'.$path.'/'.$filename;

            $slider = new Sgallery;
            $slider->file_path = date('Y-m-d');
            $slider->file_name = $filename;

            if($slider->save())://aqui es donde se dispara el error
                if($request -> hasFile('file_image')):
                    $fl = $request->file_image->storeAs($path, $filename, 'slider');
                    $img = Image::make($file_file);
                    $img->fit(256,256, function($constraint){
                        $constraint->upsize();
                    });
                    $img->save($upload_path.'/'.$path.'/t_'.$filename);
                endif;

                return back()->with('message', 'Imagen agregada con exito')->with('typealert', 'success');
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;        
}
```

Comment: Si revisas el log de la excepción probablemente te diga en qué línea se lanza, por favor actualiza la pregunta agregando eso. También podría ser útil que nos muestres que llega en el request

Comment: ¿Que valor te queda en `$upload_path` cuando haces `$upload_path = Config::get('filesystems.disks.slider.root');`?

Comment: El valor de $upload_path que me queda es este: C:\laragon\www\diamante\storage\app\public\slider

Comment: solucionado en lugar del save() use (DB::table('slider_gallery')->insert($slider) y funciono. Gracias